# Pull data from another workbook, searching in the sheets which names are in a table and depending on certain number in a row

Tags: vba, spreadsheet

please I need help with a code for:
1) Copying data from columns of spreadsheets of another workbook (Workbook2), spreadsheets names are in a table of the current workbook (Workbook1).
2) Paste selected data in the columns that contains the spreadsheet name accordingly. I'm using indicators 1 and 2 to differentiate what data to post, i.e. 1 for dates, 2 for quantities.
3) Maybe picture in the link helps for a better understanding.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXeO1.png)

4) Code I have so far is:
Sub Data()

```
Dim i As Integer

Dim DName As String
DName = Workbooks("Workbook1").Sheets("ACCT").Range(Cells(10, i))

For i = 3 To 250
    If Workbooks("Workbook1").Sheets("ACCT").Cells(3, i) = "1" Then
        Workbooks("Workbook2").Activate
        Sheets(DName).Range("A52:A500").Copy

        Workbooks("Workbook1").Activate
        Sheets("ACCT").Range(Cells(14, i)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End If
Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: Thanks. That is the problem/error that I'm having. DName is variable it is related to the column (i.e. Integer i). Maybe DName is erroneously defined as "String"? or how could I solve it?

Comment: I have spreadsheets named Pepsi, Water, etc. in another workbook (Workbook2). In Workbook 1 I have a table that aggregates certain data from the mentioned tabs, consequently I inserted the names on the tabs in row 10 of the table in order to refer to them whenever variable "i" changes (i is the variable column), so the code identifies what spreadsheet to look at. Please let me know if this explains better my requirement, thanks!

Comment: He he sorry. I'll explain in detail: 1) I need to fill the table below row 12 with data from another workbook, 2) That data is in different spreadsheets in another workbook, 3) For example, to fill column C (let's say: Pepsi Dates) in the table, I need to look for tab named "Pepsi", and copy range ("A52:A500") and paste in Range("C14") of the table, 4) for "Pepsi Quantities" I need to do the same as step 3, but with range ("B52:B500"), 5) And so on with Coke, Water, Coffee, etc. 6) So what I'm trying to do is define variable "i" as column, so when values in row 3 = 1, then refer to..

Comment: Spreadsheet which name is defined in cell C10 for Pepsi, E10 for Coke, G10 for Water, etc. 7) So when "i" changes, then column to be filled changes and the spreadsheet to look for changes as well.   By the way, THANKS in advance!

Comment: Well, that is not a solution for +200 hundred tabs...

Answer (score 0):

Here, I think this is what you're looking for:

```
Sub getInfo()
Dim cel As Range, nameRow As Range, lastCell As Variant
lastCell = Cells(10, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Address
Set nameRow = Range("A10:" & lastCell)
For Each cel In nameRow
    If cel.Value <> "Tab" And cel.Value <> "" Then
        Workbooks("Workbook2").Activate
        Sheets(cel.Value).Range("A52:A500").Copy
        Workbooks("Workbook1").Activate
        Sheets("ACCT").Cells(14, cel.Column).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End If
Next cel

End Sub
```